# create promise without constructor nor resolve reject keywords

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, vuejs2

is it possible to create a promise without using the constructor **new promise()** nor using **=>resolve** & **=>rejected** ?
check following method

```
export function getItById(id) {
  return fetch(`path`, {
    method: 'GET',
  }).then(rslt => {
    if (!rslt || !rslt.ok) {
      throw new Error('failure !');
    } else {
      return rslt.json();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: How is your question related to the snippet? This look like the typical [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I think you've seen too many code examples that contain the promise constructor mistake ("antipattern") of wrapping code like the OP in new Promise.  There's no need to, and you shouldn't.  `fetch` returns a promise, and that's what the function returns.

Comment: yes indeed, i'm trying to learn some stuff in coding and you made things obvious to me, thanks @danh

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably missing something, but it looks like everything is correct. The getItById function returns a promise. There is no need to create a promise.

So when using the function simply do

```
getItById(2).then(results => {
  console.log(results)
})
```

To answer the question "is it possible to create a promise without using new promise" the answer is yes, every http call and every database call, or a file read or write returns a promise.

Comment: it seems I'm confusing concepts, else when I'm supposed to use new promise in my code ? which is the use case it is needed for

Comment: The OP code currently returns a promise, because fetch does. The clue that fetch does is that you've called the `.then()` method on it.